# Difference between DS-5501 form of the immigration US visas and DS-260?

Tags: usa

i wanna know the difference between the DS-5501 and DS-260 forms in the US visas

Comment: This may be on topic for the travel stackexchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DS-5501 is for entering the diversity visa lottery, commonly known as the green card lottery.  DS-260 is for applying for an immigrant visa for any reason.

After someone is selected in the green card lottery, it is necessary to file a separate DS-260 application to receive the actual immigrant visa.  If any family members will be accompanying the principal immigrant, each person must file a separate DS-260.

Comment: Thanks a lot Phoog, but i have another question, shall I fill the DS-260 while I am registering in the DS-5501, or after I knew that I am selected when the lottery results are released

Comment: @MohamedAshraf that is covered in the first sentence of the second paragraph of this answer.

Comment: I have another question, in the DS-5501 instructions, it is mentioned that the first name, full name, and middle name must be written exactly as the passport, and in my passport these records are written in block capitals, does that mean in the application should i written it also in block capitals

Comment: @MohamedAshraf I don't think it matters whether the names are in block capitals, but you might as well enter them like that just to be in the safe side.

Comment: another thing, in my country we don't write the  family name, and middle name, so when filling in the DS-5501, should I say that i have no middle name, and write my first name as the family name

Comment: and it is mentioned also that if the address does not require the Postal Code, don't mention it, how does the address doesn't require the Postal Code

Comment: and what is the minimum eligible age to apply for the DS-5501 as a parent entrant

Comment: @MohamedAshraf you should enter first, last, and middle names as they are in your passport, as indicated in the instructions.  You can ask a new question about the postal code.  I'm not sure what you mean by "parent entrant" but that sounds like a new question as well.

Comment: @MohamedAshraf you should actually ask a new question about the name, too, since it's not the focus of this question.  If you do, please indicate which country issued your passport.

Comment: The country which issued my passport is Egypt

Comment: Sorry for the late reply